# Is it possible to execute a task every time an event occurs in another app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible for my app to execute some task when an event occurs in another app?

Example: A song starts playing on the device. I wanted my app to be invoked and execute some task every time it happens.

I know it is possible to implement a `PeriodicTask` which will make my tasks run every X minutes/hours... but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes but in a very limited way. You can't catch any specific events.

From [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx).

> You can use file and URI associations in Windows Phone 8 to
>   automatically launch your app when another app launches a specific
>   file type or URI scheme. When launched, a deep link URI is used to
>   send the file (a reference to the file) or URI to your app. You can
>   also use the association launching API to launch another app in the
>   same way.
>
> File associations allow your app to automatically launch when the user
>   wants to open a particular file. That file could come from a variety
>   of sources including, but not limited to: an email attachment, a
>   website via Internet Explorer, a Near Field Communications (NFC) tag or 
>   another app from the Store.

So you can enable app to app communication via `File` and `Uri` associations but there are [lots of reserved types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207065(v=vs.105).aspx) that are always handled by default programs and any other associations will be ignored.

These include audio files such as `.mp3`, `.mp4` and `.wav`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There is no way that your app can "watch" for events in other apps.

The only way is to make the other apps explicitly call your app when those events happen, which I guess is not possible in your case (that you persuade the authors to do this) so the answer is no.

Comment: What's this, an echo ;) ?